# Injecting empty transactions to repair MySQL 5.6 GTID replication doesn't work

Tags: mysql, gtid

I follows the steps on this [page](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/03/26/repair-mysql-5-6-gtid-replication-by-injecting-empty-transactions/)

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GTID_NEXT="[THE GTID SET]";
BEGIN; COMMIT;
SET GTID_NEXT="AUTOMATIC";
START SLAVE;
```

to restore the slave. But in my case, the gtid_set are as

```
Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 8b6d4795-5ad3-11e6-a31f-00259077c77a:2369-2377
Executed_Gtid_Set: 8b6d4795-5ad3-11e6-a31f-00259077c77a:1-2372:2374,8be5b0ba-5ad3-11e6-a31f-0cc47a50d072:1-12
```

When I tried to inject empty transactions to the slave and restart the slave, the 'slave_SQL_Running' is still 'No'.

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GTID_NEXT="8b6d4795-5ad3-11e6-a31f-00259077c77a:2377";
BEGIN; COMMIT;
SET GTID_NEXT=AUTOMATIC;
START SLAVE;
```

And it becomes

```
Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 8b6d4795-5ad3-11e6-a31f-00259077c77a:2369-2377
Executed_Gtid_Set: 8b6d4795-5ad3-11e6-a31f-00259077c77a:1-2372:2374:2377,8be5b0ba-5ad3-11e6-a31f-0cc47a50d072:1-12
```

and when new data is inserted to master, the slave still can't sync to the master. 
The status becomes:

```
Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 8b6d4795-5ad3-11e6-a31f-00259077c77a:2369-2378
Executed_Gtid_Set: 8b6d4795-5ad3-11e6-a31f-00259077c77a:1-2372:2374:2377,8be5b0ba-5ad3-11e6-a31f-0cc47a50d072:1-12
```

How can I make this work?

I don't want to do a full dump since there's lots of data, while fulldump takes a lot of time.

Comment: Show the error messages plz, skip the transaction 2373,2375,2376 may not help in your case;

Comment: If you mean Last_Error in slave status, it's Last_Error : Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user table' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'SET PASSWORD FOR '[username]'@'[host]'='[password]'

Comment: check the table <mysql.user> , the  '[username]'@'[host]‌​' may not exists;  Two ways : 1. the Query:'Set xxx' maybe transaction 2373, you can check the primary binlog to find the Query, and use empty  transaction to skip this Query; 2. if the  '[username]'@'[host]‌​' is not exists in slave, create this user, and restart the slave;

Comment: @GreenBlade What did the empty transaction do? I thought it would jump over gtid set 2375,2376 and 2377 (in this example). Thus no matter what's the SQL is, it wouldn't be executed, right?

Comment: Yes,  the empty transaction do nothing, just deceive the slave that it has executed this transaction, so this transaction wouldn't be executed again; Better to keep the gtid-set continuous;

Answer (score 0):

Please check below blog post.

https://www.abhinavbit.com/2019/05/gtid-replication-skip-transaction-using.html

In your case you should have run below command to skip the sql threads error.

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GTID_NEXT="8b6d4795-5ad3-11e6-a31f-00259077c77a:2375";
BEGIN; COMMIT;
SET GTID_NEXT=AUTOMATIC;
START SLAVE;
```